# Stub function to return given argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is there any built-in stub function that returns the same object it was given? I'm looking for a shortcut to `lambda x: x` (like `operator.itemgetter(1)` is a shortcut and more efficient way of saying `lambda x: x[1]`).

I technically wish for the boolean value, but `timeit` showed that `lambda x: x` was faster than `bool()` (probably because `bool` creates a new object) by 10%, and since it's being defined a few times but called many more, it makes a difference.
I only use the variable for `if` statements so I don't care whether it returns `True` or the value itself and tested using `__bool__`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but why do you need an identity function when you already have the variable that it will return?

Comment: @cricket_007 it's being used as a fill function for validation. On some objects the validation is smart, on others it's just the truth value.

Comment: I think `lambda x: x` is the usual way.

Comment: @wRAR it is **a** way, not sure if the usual. It's the same reason `operator.itemgetter` exists. You don't need it but it's more efficient and understandable.

Comment: I agree with wRAR on the `lambda`, but you might also consider the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html) module? While creating a copy of `x` (if that's acceptable) it seems good enough for your purpose.

Comment: @Bharel sure, I mean I didn't see anything better

Comment: @wRAR no problem, it's just that I'm defining it repeatedly and using it even more so if there is a shortcut which proves to be even 5% faster and more readable as an added bonus, it'll be of great use.

Comment: @Bharel `lambda obj: obj` is the idiomatic way - it was discussed and rejected as potentially going into the standard lib in 2009 - see: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-March/003647.html

Comment: @Jens creating a copy of x will be much slower I believe.